# iPad 1 apps keep crashing

Tags: ipad

My father-in-law has an original iPad and is having trouble with apps crashing. He lives 6 hours away and is not at all tech savvy so it's difficult to troubleshoot over the phone and email. So far, though, I've had him do a restor through iTunes and that didn't seem to work so I'm unsure what to do next. Any ideas?  It seems to be all apps, not just a specific app.

Comment: Is he "local" to an Apple store? If he is, make him an appointment at the Genius Bar.

Comment: Can you give some more info about how it is crashing? Immediately upon opening, or after it gets a chance to load?

Answer (score 3):

Have him sign out of the App Store in settings, then sign in again, then purchase a free app.

This resets the digital certificate that tells the device it can run apps for that account. Often these certs expire if you don't download anything for a year or more and renewing them happens when you request a new app.

When this is done, also check on iCloud backups and enable them if you can. An ounce of prevention, etc....

Comment: Alright, I've sent him instructions on how to do that with screen-shots (Thanks, Skitch!). Hopefully that will get it cleared up. Just in case, though, any other ideas?

Comment: That's a tall order for someone not used to working with tech. Make sure you look to see if there is a group he can visit with to learn the iPad together. As long as they want to figure it out - this is the most likely cause and also something an interested person can learn in most cases.